# data.table expand sub list use names by reference

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table that I've created from JSON data, which has some nested list columns that I'd like to make into their own columns (it also has embedded null values, which is why I'm using `do.call(rbind, list)` rather than `rbindlist`) :

Example Data:

```
# Make some sample JSON
rawjson <- lapply(1:10,
               function(x) list(stats = list(stat1 = sample(LETTERS,1),
                                             stat2 = sample(LETTERS,1), 
                                             stat3 = NULL), 
                                othervar = runif(1)))
#convert to data.table
dtjson <- data.table(do.call(rbind, rawjson))
```

When we check our output, we see we have a list column called `stats`

```
> dtjson
     stats  othervar
 1: <list> 0.6980694
 2: <list> 0.1696928
 3: <list> 0.6168877
 4: <list> 0.4322135
 5: <list> 0.6941624
 6: <list> 0.3354516
 7: <list> 0.7159235
 8: <list> 0.2019412
 9: <list> 0.8908848
10: <list> 0.4643908
```

Now, I can turn that stats column inside out with `purrr::transpose`

```
library(purrr)
> dtjson[,purrr::transpose(stats)]
    stat1 stat2 stat3
 1:     U     G  NULL
 2:     J     X  NULL
 3:     D     E  NULL
 4:     F     V  NULL
 5:     V     W  NULL
 6:     Z     I  NULL
 7:     R     O  NULL
 8:     A     H  NULL
 9:     L     R  NULL
10:     A     M  NULL
```

But, I'm at a loss as to how to assign each of these new columns by reference.

I tried:

```
> dtjson[,names(purrr::transpose(stats)) := purrr::transpose(stats)]
Error in transpose(stats) : object 'stats' not found
```

On the other hand, This works:

```
 dtjson[, paste0('V',1:3) := purrr::transpose(stats)]
```

but it requires me to know beforehand exactly how many columns are going to result from `transpose(stats)`, which I may not know until I transpose stats. And preferably, I'd like to keep the internal names as defined inside the list column, whatever they are.

Is there any way to use the names that the list already has to assign by reference?

EDIT: transpose from purrr was doing the job, not data.table::transpose

Comment: Yeah, you can read the names from the first entry like `names(dtjson$stats[[1]]) := `, right?

Comment: Hm, actually your "This works" code does not work for me (running devel version 1.9.7 of the package). However, `dtjson[, transpose(lapply(stats, unlist))]` does, sort of.

Comment: that works! also works as `names(transpose(dtjson$stats))`, if I don't want a dependence on the first row of stats, though that adds a lot of computation time. I'd accept that answer, since in this case I know that all names are defined in every row.

Comment: hmm, I'm also on 1.9.7, and when I ran it the first time that worked, started with a fresh environment and it clearly doesn't... that's weird.

Comment: Ah! I see the issue, I had purrr loaded, and it was using that version of transpose, let me adjust my question

Comment: Ok, something similar has been discussed/proposed: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1543#issuecomment-193731090

Comment: Great! thanks for posting on there as well, if you want to post the current version as a solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
dtjson[, names(s <- purrr::transpose(dtjson$stats)) := s]
rm(s)
```

I borrowed this [from @MichaelChirico's post](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1543#issue-135850082) on the data.table issue tracker.

---

An alternative, not relying on `s` being an unused variable name, is

```
dtjson[, names(dtjson$stats[[1]]) := purrr::transpose(stats)]
```

Hopefully there will be a better way to go about this eventually.